# How to remove a border that's not declared in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, accordion, user-experience

So I've Created an Accordion menu on a page, however, there seems to be a shaded border or a shadow around the actual accordion that's not created or declared.

I've gone through and experimented with removing any lines that consist of creating a border, padding, margin, and shadow. Yet I'm unable to remove it or have it disguised.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.accordion {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}
.accordion-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.accordion-item-header {
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion-item-header::after {
  content: "\02C7";
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  color: orange;
}
.accordion-item-header.active::after {
  content: "\02C6";
}
.accordion-item-body {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.accordion-item-body-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #34495e, transparent) 1;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  html {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-item-header">
      Title for card 1
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item-body">
      <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
        Section for Card 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-item-header">
      Title for Card 2
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item-body">
      <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
        Section for Card 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I Have Attached an Image here to show what the current output is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not round the whole accordian, just each element within it.

Take out the box-shadow in - or indeed the whole of - this:

```
.accordion-item {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

You might also want to get rid of the border given in :

```
.accordion-item-body-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #34495e, transparent) 1;
}
```

but I can't tell from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any border, look at the snippet. Is this the full code? Don't you miss something?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }
  .accordion-item {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .accordion-item-header {
    padding: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 1rem;
    min-height: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .accordion-item-header::after {
    content: "\02C7";
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    color: orange;
  }
  .accordion-item-header.active::after {
    content: "\02C6";
  }
  .accordion-item-body {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  .accordion-item-body-content {
    padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #34495e, transparent) 1;
  }
  
  @media(max-width:767px) {
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-item-header">
      Title for card 1
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item-body">
      <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
        Section for Card 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-item-header">
      Title for Card 2
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item-body">
      <div class="accordion-item-body-content">
        Section for Card 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is in fact the full code. Unfortunately, because I'm new to the community, I can't post pictures directly, they are converted to a link, and the link attached contains the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZJRJ.png Could this be an Angular Thing?

Comment: I don't use Angluar, so I am not sure, but It could be from code added by Anular by default. Did you inspect the bordered element with developer tools in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I inspected it, but it's not showing it as its own individual entity.